# What does filename.$$ means in sed command

Tags: unix, sed

Can someone explain me the meaning of this line :

```
wget -q -O - $URL | sed 's/<str name="id">/\&/g' > tmp.$$ 2>/dev/null
```

After hitting the URL, it's searching for the pattern 
     
but what's the meaning of tmp.$$ here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$$` is the current process id in most of the commonly used unix based shells .  It's probably being used to create a unique filename so multiple instances can run the same time and not squash each others temp files.

Comment: Thanks Ray..But a numeric 2 after that indicates what??

Comment: @user2820678 the numeric 2 is part of the `2>` it's redirecting the standard error out to `/dev/null`

Comment: And the sed is globaly replace the `<str name="id">` (the result of which is written to the temp file)

Comment: @user2820678 does this answer your question?